# Dynamic page for multiple links

Tags: php

How can i change the url

`http://server.com/windows/antivirus-software.php?**SoftID=1**`

to

`http://server.com/Accuretasoft.com/windows/antivirus-software.php?**name=some_text**`

When I change SoftID from integer to text it responses error
i am using:

```
<?php
$dbh=mysql_connect("xyz","userxyz","password"); 
mysql_select_db("somedb");  
$SoftID = $_GET['SoftID']; 
$row_sql="SELECT * From table Where SoftID=$SoftID"; 
$row_query = mysql_query($row_sql); 
$rowSoft = mysql_fetch_assoc($row_query); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using strings in query, you have to enclose them in quotes like

```
$row_sql="SELECT * From table Where SoftID='$SoftID'";
```